# Firestore snapshot listener as a service?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-service

This question might be asked before. But I couldn't find any relevant information related to my query. So my question is can I use a firestore listener inside a service so that it will run in the background even when the application is minimized. Can we add a firestore listener inside a service class ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want in an Android Service.  A service is just a way to tell Android that you have some work to do that doesn't necessarily have a UI attached to it.  If you want to leave a service running as much as possible, you will have to make it a foreground service, which means you're obliged to provide an icon for the notification curtain, so the user knows that your app is consuming resources on the device.

While your service is keeping the Android app process alive, you can certainly have a listener attached to some document or query, and it will update as the results change.  But be aware that you will be charged for each of the updates, it will cost the user bandwidth, and it will drain their battery.

Answer (score -2):

I do not have a sufficient reputation so I am writing here.

Yes you can use firestore listner in service.

Comment: Could you post a link or an example or something?
I seem to be missing something when I try to implement this.

Comment: recently I am posting a repo of best location update where I am using a firestore on service to save location on firestore. [Repo Link](https://github.com/BlackBlind567/Location_Updates-Background_Foreground)